Unable to locate element - Exception
URL - https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory-item.html?id=4
How to access the $ mark on this Xpath?
//*[@id="inventory_item_container"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/text()[1] 

I'm getting an error on IntelliJ:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="cart_contents_container"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/text()[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.185)

expected for below
actualText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"inventory_item_container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]")).getText(); 

for this actual text should be = $.

The URL which you have shared is of no use if one has to log-in to see the targeted element. Since you haven't shared the username and password, no one can reproduce the issue. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. You need to either share the log in credentials or share the HTML of the page in the text form.

If you know that the div element has the text $, then you could select it with the XPath //div[.='$']

If you want to access the price of the item then you can use find by class because there is a class where "$" is mentioned. Also, the XPATH that you have provided is wrong or incorrect.

